# What is an input to this program that will result in a correct validation?

Tags: python

I am new to python programming. Our professor asked us to write down what we think the answer is to this question.

"What is an input to this program that will result in a correct validation?"

I was confused and did not know how to answer. I thought I had to compile the code and run it to see if there are any syntax errors. Can anyone help me out with it?

```
import sys

def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Invalid args"
    return
  password = sys.argv[1]
  builder = 0
  for c in password:
    builder += ord(c)
  if builder == 1000 and len(password) == 10 and ord(password[1]) == 83:
    print "correct"
  else:
    print "incorrect"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: The question is; what is an example password you can pass to this program that would print `correct`. You should follow the steps in the code (possibly using pen and paper) and try to understand the validation rules.

Comment: You're not being asked to find a problem with the code. The code works, you're supposed to figure out what it does.

Comment: As a simple example, if the program were `if a == 3: print "correct"; else: print "incorrect"`, the answer would be `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Walking through it without giving away the answer:

```
for c in password:
    builder += ord(c)
```

'ord()' takes in a char and returns the value associated with that character. We then increment 'builder' by that much.

```
 if builder == 1000...
```

So once we finish converting each character value and summing them all together, we need to get to 1000.

```
...and len(password) == 10...
```

The password also has to be 10 characters long.

```
...and ord(password[1]) == 83:
```

Finally, the second letter has to have a value of 83. Google should help you figure that part out.

As an aside,

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Invalid args"
```

When reading in args, the first arg is the file name, so basically you cannot have a password that is "my cat is fat". In other words, it has to be one 'word'.